# Change background img IF class="active"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the background image of a div when I click on a thumbnail.
The background needs to change based on what thumbnail is "active"

My code I tried;

```
$('#sliderThumbs li a').click( function() {
    if($('#sliderThumbs li.entalk.active') === true) {
        $('#slider').css('background','url(i/slider-bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 -550px');
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
<ul id="sliderThumbs">
    <li class="intellibalast">
        <a href="#"><span>Intelliblast&trade; unit</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="dolfin">
        <a href="#"><span>Dolfin&trade; sensor</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="entalk active">
        <a href="#"><span>EnTalk&trade;</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So when I click on say.. Intellibalast, that li will then turn to class="intellibalast active"

The background of  Will need to change based on what li is active (I have 3 different images, each corresponding to the li class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Used .is instead of hasClass and removed ; from the css value.

Try this:

```
$('#sliderThumbs li a').click( function() {
    if($(this).closest("li").is(".entalk, .active")) {
        $('#slider').css('background','url(../i/slider-bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 -550px');
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately.
I noticed my CSS section was wrong, I've fixed that now though, will edit my original post

Comment: On second thoughts - This was basically correct
I've adjusted the hasClass("entalk.active")
So simply;
hasClass("entalk")
and setup an else if and else condition for the other 2 classes.
Working fine now.

Thanks.

Comment: @jQuery: Updated the post..pls chk

Comment: Works fine :)
Any idea if/how I can add some animation to the change?
I'd like the background to slide up when it changes, I've tried .animate at the end of the condition but it doesn't seem to work